# needsSoftKeyboard() method is NOT available

Tags: android, apache-flex, text

I have installed

Flash Builder Burrito 
Sdk 4.5
and
Flash Player 10.2 
Air 2.0

but there is not needsSoftKeyboard() method in my view

```
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="Home" xmlns:views="views.*"
        destructionPolicy="none" xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" >
```

and this is NOT in

```
<s:TextInput x="194" y="212" />
```

I have read about this method and about SoftKeyboardEvent but i could not access softkeyboard method and SoftKeyboardEvent as well.

What is the reason?
May be i am missing something.

Please help me.
I am making a Flex Mobile Project in which user can add text at run time.

How can i open soft keyboard to add text at run time.

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question again, I think there's code missing. Also, please use the code formatter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What control (not the View) are you trying to set this on?  From the documentation, it is not a method, but a property on a control.  It is not needed on TextInput because it comes up automatically (and can't be made to false):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WS82181550ec4a666a39bafe0312d9a274c00-8000.html

For instance, `NumericStepper` might benefit from `needsSoftKeyboard`.

There are also three soft keyboard events on the controls:

`softKeyboardActivate, softKeyboardActivating, softKeyboardDeactivate`

More info here:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSfffb011ac560372f6bc38fcc12e0166e73b-8000.html

Comment: Thanks Brain i have also checked this for text input but it is not available in this tag  '<s:TextInput x="127" y="250"/>' and if if write this a compiler error occure. Cannot resolve attribute 'needsSoftKeyboard' for component type spark.components.TextInput. I think i am missing something can you please guess why i can't be able to access this property? i am testing this app on windows xp.

Comment: @Ghulam Murtaza: What version of the SDK are you using?  Are you still using the beta from October?  I am using 4.5 and the Spark TextInput does, indeed, have `needsSoftKeyboard` even though that particular control is supposed to ignore it.  Make sure you are using the latest SDK and tooling: http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-builder.html

Comment: @Brain:It is now working with Flex 4.5. Thanks very much Brain Genisio

Comment: @Ghulam Murtaza: Good to know it.  Please mark this answer correct and/or up-vote it.  This site runs on cred points :)